# SQL Server Select in XML field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, xml

I need a help with the situation below:

In my table SQLServer 2012 have a field with xml values, I would like to make a select of the data in that field and show the result in the form columns.

[image: Image1]

```
<row> 
  <ID_Cota>162986</ID_Cota>
  <ID_Taxa_Plano>1000</ID_Taxa_Plano>
  <ID_Plano_Venda>1020</ID_Plano_Venda>
  <ID_Pessoa>18522</ID_Pessoa>
</row>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Use `CROSS APPLY` and the [.nodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188282.aspx) method of the XML data-type, eg something like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.yourTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.yourTable
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.yourTable ( 
    rowId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
    ST_Registro_Del XML
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.yourTable ( ST_Registro_Del )
SELECT '<row> 
  <ID_Cota>162986</ID_Cota>
  <ID_Taxa_Plano>1000</ID_Taxa_Plano>
  <ID_Plano_Venda>1020</ID_Plano_Venda>
  <ID_Pessoa>18522</ID_Pessoa>
</row>'
GO


SELECT 
    r.c.value('(ID_Cota/text())[1]', 'INT' ) AS ID_Cota,
    r.c.value('(ID_Taxa_Plano/text())[1]', 'INT' ) AS ID_Cota,
    r.c.value('(ID_Plano_Venda/text())[1]', 'INT' ) AS ID_Cota,
    r.c.value('(ID_Pessoa/text())[1]', 'INT' ) AS ID_Cota
FROM dbo.yourTable yt
    CROSS APPLY yt.ST_Registro_Del.nodes('row') r(c)
WHERE rowId = 1
```

Here are my results:

[image: test results]

The `.nodes` method returns a resultset from XML.  Use the `text()` accessor for a performance boost when querying untyped XML ( ie no XSD is associated with the XML column and the `[1]` ordinal, which is a shorthand way of saying "get me the first element you find".

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I would be among the first to say that my xQuery is *rusty* but the following worked for me:

```
WITH    xml_string
AS      (
        SELECT val = CAST('<row><ID_Cota>162986</ID_Cota><ID_Taxa_Plano>1000</ID_Taxa_Plano><ID_Taxa_Venda>1020</ID_Taxa_Venda><ID_Pessoa>18522</ID_Pessoa></row>' AS XML)
        )
SELECT  val,
        (val).value('(/row[1]/ID_Cota[1])', 'INT'),
        (val).value('(/row[1]/ID_Taxa_Plano[1])', 'INT'),
        (val).value('(/row[1]/ID_Taxa_Venda[1])', 'INT'),
        (val).value('(/row[1]/ID_Pessoa[1])', 'INT')
FROM    xml_string;
```

---

Edited to run query from a table:

```
WITH    xml_string
AS      (
        SELECT val = CAST('<row><ID_Cota>162986</ID_Cota><ID_Taxa_Plano>1000</ID_Taxa_Plano><ID_Taxa_Venda>1020</ID_Taxa_Venda><ID_Pessoa>18522</ID_Pessoa></row>' AS XML)
        )
SELECT  val
INTO    ST_Registro_Del
FROM    xml_string;

-- run from the table here:
SELECT  val,
        ID_Cota       = (val).value('(/row[1]/ID_Cota[1])', 'INT'),
        ID_Taxa_Plano = (val).value('(/row[1]/ID_Taxa_Plano[1])', 'INT'),
        ID_Taxa_Venda = (val).value('(/row[1]/ID_Taxa_Venda[1])', 'INT'),
        ID_Pessoa     = (val).value('(/row[1]/ID_Pessoa[1])', 'INT')
FROM    ST_Registro_Del
```

Comment: and how do I use the "ST_Registro_Del" my table :?

Answer (score 1):

Below will help you

```
declare @sql xml 
set @sql = '<row> 
  <ID_Cota>162986</ID_Cota>
  <ID_Taxa_Plano>1000</ID_Taxa_Plano>
  <ID_Plano_Venda>1020</ID_Plano_Venda>
  <ID_Pessoa>18522</ID_Pessoa>
</row>'

select s.n.value('(ID_Cota)[1]', 'int') as ID_Cota
        ,s.n.value('(ID_Taxa_Plano)[1]', 'int') as ID_Taxa_Plano
        ,s.n.value('(ID_Plano_Venda)[1]', 'int') as ID_Plano_Venda
        ,s.n.value('(ID_Pessoa)[1]', 'int') as ID_Pessoa
from @sql.nodes('/row') as s(n)
```

[image]